# Shortcut to Open finder without clicking the icon

Tags: keyboard, finder, shortcut

I want to save a click, is there a shortcut that regardless of which app I have in my active view, it opens Finder into view?

Comment: You could make an Automator Service that uses Apple Script to bring the Finder forward, and assign a key command to it. You could just use Command Tab to  select the Finder, though.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when it "opens" Finder? Finder is always active, even if no Finder window is open.

Comment: More context: I have a bunch of windows open and two monitors, Finder is indeed opened all the time but sometimes buried beneath other windows, I just need it to pop back up into view.